# " added to start of string when pulling in words from MS Word table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm pulling in values from a word table, comparing it to a few options using an IF statement. The problem I'm having is Word adds a quotation to the start of the string pulled in from Word. I've tried removing the CHR but that does not work.

I've cut the code down to highlight the issue.

I've tried removing the CHR and chopping the first Chr, but that does not work. This problem does not occur when it pulls in a number.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Minbody()

     Dim check(1 To 1000, 1 To 1000) As Variant '''''''''''''''''''''
     Dim Actionitem(1 To 1000) As Variant


     check(1, 1) = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("PTable").Range.Tables(1).Cell(3, 5)


    check(1, 1) = Replace(check(1, 1), Chr(7), "") '<<< remove end of cell marker



            If check(1, 1) = "NA" Then

            MsgBox check(1, 1)

            Actionitem(1) = check(1, 1)

            Else
            End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you *sure* it's a `"` and not a `“` or a `”`?  Word likes to replace double quotes with the left and right "handed" versions.

Comment: When I hover over it shows ". If I add the line MsgBox check(1,1) it simply displays NA.

Comment: 1. Assign the cell content to a string variable. 2) Put a break point in the code right after the assignement. 3) In the VBA Immediate Window query: `?Len(s)` and compare the length of the string with the number of characters you see in the table cell. Then `Asc(s)` to get the character code of the first character in the string. What is it? Also: Where are you seeing the quotation marks? In the MsgBox or somewhere else? Is the cell content all Latin characters and formatted with a "European" language or is it something else?

Comment: When I assign check (1 to 1000, 1 to 1000) as string I get a Compile Error Type mismatch so I left it as variant
In the Immediate window It outputted a length of 4. I should only have two characters, NA. The Asc returns character 78 which is N. 
I only see the “ at the star of the string when I break the code and hover my curser over the variable. The “ disappears when I use a msgbox to display the string. I’m using font Calibri for the entire word file.

Comment: Thank you both for the help, I have sourced this issue to an "enter" Chr (13). Removing this from the string allows the code to properly run.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub Minbody()
     Dim check(1 To 1000, 1 To 1000) As Variant
     Dim Actionitem(1 To 1000) As Variant

With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("PTable").Range.Tables(1).Cell(3, 5).Range
    check(1, 1) = Left(.Text, Len(.Text) - 2)
End With

If check(1, 1) = "NA" Then
    MsgBox check(1, 1)
    Actionitem(1) = check(1, 1)
End If
End Sub
```